# Codeigniter send curl to laravel api Oauth2

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, codeigniter-3

I have a project that runs in CI3 and he need's to connect in Laravel 5.5 API with OAUTH2.

Now my current code in codeigniter is this:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url_api);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'login' => $login,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.APP_ACCESSTOKEN
    ));


    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    $result = json_decode($buffer);

     if(isset($result->status) && $result->status == 'success')
    {
        echo 'User has been updated.';
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'Something has gone wrong '.$url_api .'<br>?'.$result.'<br>';
    }
    exit;
```

I have no idea of how to send login and token on this get request. Can someone give me an example? It's not authenticating. However, if I remove the route from auth, it work's fine, so its auth problem.

I searched a lot, but no success :(

Comment: Have you tested it with Postman? Also Laravel code would be good to see here so edit your question with it.

Comment: @Tpojka thank's for your answer. Yes, with postman it goes well. it already worked from Laravel to Laravel, but from Codeigniter to Laravel, I'm facing some issues. What part of Laravel's code you wish do see?

Comment: I thought of code of that webhook. But you proved in other two cases it was working (Postman and Laravel request). Is code the same between CodeIgniter and Laravel application that is working? Can you check PHP (and apache) error/access logs?

Comment: @Tpojka now I tested in postman and it's not authenticating. I'll fix it and come back to answer you ok?

Comment: @Tpojka it happens you'r right, it was something else! Now, how can I choose your answer as correct one?

Comment: Actually I didn't help but rather told you what to check in favour to let me know what is happening there. Feel free to write an answer describing what was the error and how did you fix it. You can accept your own answer if there is no other solutions but everyone can vote up for that for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

It was something else messing up my tests.

For no reason, my token, user and code was simply gone from database. I just run db:seed and generate a new token and it was fine.